# Beginner Python, splitting data

Tags: python

I'm really new to python so this is probably a really stupid problem but I honestly have no idea what I'm doing and I have spent hours trying to get this to work. 
I need to have the user input a date (in string form) and then use this date to return some data (The function get_data_for_date has already previously been created and works fine, I just have to call it manually in the console and enter the date for it to work currently ). The data then needs to be split when it is returned. Any help would be appreciated, or even if you could just point me in the right direction.

```
dateStr = raw_input('Date? ')

def load_data(dateStr):

    def get_data_for_date(dateStr):
        text = data

        return data.split('\n')
```

Comment: I cannot follow what you're trying to do. Can you give us an example of what a date is and what should happen when you run your program?

Comment: The user will enter a date in the format DD-MM-YYYY (for example 01-02-2013) 
I then want to call the function get_data_for_date and use the date entered by the user to get the set of data that corresponds to that date. I then want to return this data to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do away with the outer function `load_data()` as this does nothing (in the code that you posted). You then need to call the function `get_data_for_date()` passing to it the `dateStr` entered by the user. This is the function call `get_data_for_date(dateStr)` as show here:

```
def get_data_for_date(dateStr):
    text = data
    return data.split('\n')

dateStr = raw_input('Date? ')
data = get_data_for_date(dateStr)
print data
```

There is an obvious problem in your `get_data_for_date()` function: `data` is never assigned to, and `text` is never used, so here is an illustrative version of it:

```
def get_data_for_date(dateStr):
    data = "1. Line 1\n2. Line 2\n3. Line 3"
    return data.split('\n')

dateStr = raw_input('Date? ')
data = get_data_for_date(dateStr)

>>> print data
['1. Line 1', '2. Line 2', '3. Line 3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, really didn't quite understood the code but if you need to split user input data try this piece of code:

```
dateStr = raw_input('Date? ').split('char')
```

where char is the character or a string you want to split your input by

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are some unnecessary lines in the code but eventually this code will return you the list of Dates if given a dates in a string format like this,
"Date 1\nDate 2\nDate 3 " .

Note : Date 1, Date 2, and Date 3 are actual date values

Output : [Date1,Date2,Date3]

Or you might be trying to remove newline at the end of date input
so for that you can use strip function
or 
simply return dateStr.split('\n')[0]